# Default path on multiple nginx ingress rewrite

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Here is my situation, I'm on kubernetes (ingress), with two docker images: one dedicated to the web and the second one to the api.

Under the next configuration (at the end of the message): `/web` will show the front-end that will make some calls to `/api`, **all good there**.

but `/` is a 404 since nothing is defined, I couldn't find a way to tell in the ingress config that `/` should redirect to `/web`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - demo.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: demo.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: api-app
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /web
        backend:
          serviceName: web-app
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: You can use rewrite-target but you'll need to split the ingress into two. If you create two ingresses with different names but same host and and different paths I believe that should work. It may sound less efficient but it's just a different way of specifying the routing rules.

Comment: Or just remove rewrite-target if that works for your /api too. I think you only need to separate if one needs the target rewritten and the other doesn't.

Comment: Do feel free to let me know if the comments didn't prove helpful.

Comment: @RyanDawson I pass it to the team, as soon they try it, I will let you know. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @RyanDawson and Miguel Angel Acevedo, do you have a working example?
I really need to make this work as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ChristianSaiki what is it you're looking for an example of? Rewriting the target for one service and not another?

Comment: Exactly, @RyanDawson! 
That would be much appreciated.

Comment: @ChristianSaiki Have posted now as an answer - hopefully this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on what your frontend and backend apps expect in terms of paths. Normally the frontend will [need to be able to find the backend on a certain external path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148660/communication-from-pod-to-pod-on-same-node-inside-kubernetes-in-gcp) and in your case it sounds like your backend needs to be made available on a different path externally (`/api`) from what it works on within the cluster (`/`). You can rewrite the target for requests to the api so that `/api` will go to `/` when the request is routed to the backend:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress-backend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - demo.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: demo.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: api-app
          servicePort: 8080
```

And you can also define a separate ingress (with a different name) for the frontend that does not rewrite the target, so that a request to `/web` will go to `/web` for it:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress-frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - demo.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: demo.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - path: /web
        backend:
          serviceName: web-app
          servicePort: 80
```