# Kubernetes communication between pods using REST

Tags: java, rest, kubernetes, resttemplate

Right now I got an architecture like this:

```
          internet
             |
   [ IngressController ]
        |          |
   [ Ingress A] [ Ingress B]
   --|-----|--  --|-----|--
   [ Service A] [ Service B]
         |            |
     [ Pod A]     [ Pod B]
```

So if `Service A` request data from `Service B` it is using the `full qualified name`, e.g.

> `ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(host.com/serviceB, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);`

As all of them are in the same cluster I would try to change the architecture to improve communication between the services. I imagined something like this:

```
          internet
             |
   [ IngressController ]
        |          |
   [ Ingress A] [ Ingress B]
   --|-----|--  --|-----|--
   [ Service A]-[ Service B]
         |            |
     [ Pod A]     [ Pod B]
```

So the services would be allowed to request each other via the name only or something. I am just not sure how to realize this using `REST-Services`.

Comment: So, your POD A could just call POD B via SERVICE B, e.g. by calling http://nameofserviceb:8080, just make sure your pods and services expose the webserver port. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: have you tried to access **service B** via **Pod A** directly? ...first, test it with curl or telnet inside a pod...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Service B` by it's [Kubernetes DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and it should connect directly without going through the ingress.

To clarify `Service A` doesn't talk to `Service B`, but rather `Pod A` talks to `Service B` and `Pod B` talks to `Service A`. So, long all pods and services are in the same [Kubernetes namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/), you can communicate with the service with the service name as the hostname and that will resolve to the internal IP address of the service and then forward the traffic to the pod.

If the pods happen to be in different namespaces you would connect with the namespace name added to the service: `<service-name>.<namespace-name>` or with `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! How does this work for redirects? Lets say I got a static href link?

Comment: @elp if you mean from html then it doesn't work for that. That is hosted in a Pod but runs in a browser on the client machine so needs to use external access via your ingress. You can only use service names for internal access in server-side backend code that executes within the cluster.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148660/communication-from-pod-to-pod-on-same-node-inside-kubernetes-in-gcp on this