# Reactjs in kubernetes getting error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when using axios "GET" in backend express using DNS service endpoint

Tags: reactjs, express, kubernetes, connection-refused

I'm trying to deploy my ReactJs in Kubernetes and my backend server is running ExpresssJs (cors enabled).

But I'm getting this error message net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in my Reactjs chrome console when trying to GET.

**GET https://express-api.dev-d.svc.cluster.local/v1/api/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

but when trying to execute the CURL command in my Reactjs pod to my ExpressJs URL there are no issues at all I'm getting the right response.

Not sure if this is a limitation in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

After further research, seems this is not possible from what I've read.

from here: [Communication from Pod to Pod on same node inside kubernetes in GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148660/communication-from-pod-to-pod-on-same-node-inside-kubernetes-in-gcp)