# Kubernetes SSO Github OAuth for multiple applications

Tags: jenkins, github, kubernetes, oauth-2.0

So here is the deal. I am using Kubernetes and I want to protect the applications inside of the cluster. Therefore I added an oauth2-proxy and, in case the user is not logged in, it is redirected to GitHub. After the login is done, the user is redirected to the app ([Login Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xHSE.png)). For now, I have two dummy deployments of an echo-http server (echo1 and echo2) and Jenkins. I am doing everything locally with minikube, so please don't mind the domain names.

In Jenkins, I installed the Github OAuth plugin and configured it as said in the multiple posts I found (e.g., [Jenkins GitHub OAuth](https://faun.pub/github-oauth-for-jenkins-d21d76a3ff09)). Also created the GitHub OAuth application and set the callback. Since I want to have SSO for multiple applications besides Jenkins, I set the call back to https://auth.int.example.com/oauth2/callback instead of https://jenkins.int.example.com/securityRealm/finishLogin. Therefore, after login on the GitHub, I get redirected to the Jenkins webpage but as a guest. If I try to log in, I end up in an error.
I used Helm to setup the oauth2-proxy (k8s-at-home/oauth2-proxy)

Am I missing something?

These are the ingress configuration of the oauth2-proxy and ingress controller that I am using.

Nginx Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: echo-ingress
 annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://auth.int.example.com/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://auth.int.example.com/oauth2/start?rd=https%3A%2F%2F$host$request_uri"
 spec:
   tls:
    - hosts:
      - echo1.int.example.com
      - echo2.int.example.com
      - jenkins.int.example.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-prod
    rules:
    - host: echo1.int.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: echo1
            servicePort: 80
    - host: echo2.int.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: echo2
            servicePort: 80
    - host: jenkins.int.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path:
          backend:
            serviceName: jenkins-service
            servicePort: 8080
        - path: /securityRealm/finishLogin
          backend:
            serviceName: jenkins-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

OAuth2-proxy Configuration

```
config:
  existingSecret: oauth2-proxy-creds

extraArgs:
  whitelist-domain: .int.example.com
  cookie-domain: .int.example.com
  provider: github

authenticatedEmailsFile:
  enabled: true
  restricted_access: |-
    my_email@my_email.com 

ingress:
  enabled: true
  path: /
  hosts:
    - auth.int.example.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
  tls:
    - secretName: oauth2-proxy-https-cert
      hosts:
        - auth.int.example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice auth architecture you are building there!

I would say that you may have have overlooked the fact that Jenkins has its own authentication. You also need to [configure Jenkins itself to allow Oauth2 access via Github](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-oauth/).

So what is really going on? Your Oauth proxy solution is great. You can build apps in your k8s cluster, without having to worry about user management or authentication directly from your app.
However, this is useful only for apps that don't have their own authentication mechanisms.
The Oauth proxy is simply protecting the access to the backend webserver. Once you are allowed by the proxy, you interact directly with the app, so if the app requires authentication, so will you as end user.

My advice would be to use the Oauth proxy for apps that don't have user management mechanisms, and leave open access to apps that have authentication mechanisms, like Jenkins. Otherwise you could end up with double authentication (proxy *and* Jenkins in this case), which is not so great.

Then, to keep the high level concept of accessing your cluster with Github accounts, you need to configure those user-based apps to also make use of Github Oauth2. This way the access to the cluster is homogeneus (you just need your Github account), but the actual integration has two different types: apps that don't require user management (they are protected by the Oauth proxy), and apps with authentication, which are then configured with Github's Oauth2 independently.

Comment: Thank you :) I am still a newbie when it comes to this! So once again thank you for your time and explanation :) 
Let me just ask another thing: is there any way I can forward the authentication of oauth-proxy to Jenkins? The idea is to have a Single Sign on to all of the applications :/ For now, as you said, I have to authenticate two times which is a bit nonsense. 

Thank you again :)

Comment: you are most welcome! I'm afraid I don't know of ways of forwarding these credentials. However, from Openid/Oauth2 perspective, ideally, every app would require their own `client id` and `client secret`. I fully understand this is more work, but consider that the SSO concept remains intact. As end user, you can access proxy-protected apps **and** integrated apps like Jenkins with Github, and you don't need to log twice.
My advice is to expose Jenkins ingress without the proxy, and define it as a separate app in Github. You would then have 2 Github Oauth2/Openid apps, Jenkins and the proxy.

Comment: Thank you once again! :) I am following the idea that you gave me but yet I have another question if you don't mind; lets say that I go to echo1.example.com (dummy HTTP server protected by the OAuth proxy) and then to the Jenkins domain. When I enter I am still a guest unless I click on the login button. After that, I get authenticated immediately without being redirected to GitHub again, which is awesome. But is it possible to immediately login into Jenkins without needing to enter the page as a guest and then click on the login button?
Cheers :)

Comment: Hi again! Yes there is! but again this is up to the backend service. For Jenkins, I use plugin `openid-plugin` (because my Oauth2/OIDC provider is `keycloak`). This plugin has an option to set `SSO Mode` - See https://github.com/jenkinsci/openid-plugin#sso-mode, which does exactly what you want (and I love that SSO feeling too). I couldn't find that option on that `Github Auth` plugin that you mentioned, but it either has it somewhere, or you can use any other openid/Oauth2/oidc plugin. They should all be compatible with Github (even tho they may require a bit more config).

Comment: Thank you again for your answer !! :) Just another question if you don't mind :P In the example that I am using, the OAuth proxy has a different hostname than the web apps (echo1, echo2). Is there a way to use paths instead of hostnames for both the apps to be protected and the OAuth proxy share the same hostname for everything instead of using different ones? :)

Comment: Well I'd say yes again! Check the `paths` section of the ingress yaml in this question (**the question's yaml, not the answer**): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702872/default-path-on-multiple-nginx-ingress-rewrite
and if it works, I'd suggest to create a new question with your multi-path comment/question, so we can have these two last comments as a different question/answer (as you can see the actual problem in that referenced question is not exactly yours). If you decide to do so, you can perhaps reference it here in a comment.

Comment: sorry, I see you actually have multipath in your very own question already. Isn't something almost like that what you need? I mean just create new host like `internal.example.com` or `dummy-apps.example.com` and use multipath on that host (always referring to the ingress file), like you do with jenkins' multipath

Comment: Thank you :) I eventually figured it out hehe :) Thank you again for all of your help :) Cheers !!